# Multi Tenancy with Azure AD Auth With Web App API

Tags: azure, architecture, active-directory

I have a classical 3-tier app (Database, API & UI) running on Azure cloud. Now I want to extend this app and enable it for a different set of customer base. So for now I'm having users pertaining to Company A in the Database. I'm using Azure AD for Authentication and once Auth is successful via logging in, the users can call the necessary API's.

I now want to extend this set up to Company B. I already identified that I would not use the same Database to hold the data for Company B. So I will have a new database to accomodate all the data for Company B. I will use the same UI & the API to server both Company A and Company B.

Right now, I'm using Azure AD for creating JWT tokens that I validate in my API upon every API call. With this multi tenant set up, I now also have to identify from this Token which Company the API call belongs to such that I can connect to the appropriate database. I have been reading about Multi tenancy in Azure AD, but not sure if this is the right thing I should be doing. Any ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When designing multi-tenant application, you have to choose from several patterns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns

Depending on many features:

Tenant Isolation, Scalability requirements, development complexity, operational complexity and customizations. The biggest factors would be security and isolation.

From what you described , it seems you are in the multi-tenant app with database per tenant.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns#d-multi-tenant-app-with-database-per-tenant

Comment: Here is a sample application that show cases how to do it using Azure AD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading up on B2B and B2C collaboration in Azure Active Directory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/compare-with-b2c

Generally, I don't think you are doing anything wrong.